# would i be able to share ram from my server to a PC connected

Tags: cloud, server-side, ram

I have a server I was wondering if my could make it so that when people connect to it it, I could dedicate them some of the ram from the server to use as on top of their current ram as if it was on their PC.
I know there would be problems with latency and other things, but I am simply wondering if it could be done and if it can would it be possible for me to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it is impossible to use your server RAM directly since the real RAM is a device attached to a motherboard and there are no high-level abstractions in communication between ram and processor.

But it might be possible (I am not sure) to use server RAM as a SWAP file.

Consider the following hypothetical approach:

1. mount RAM as a file system on the server (it is possible on Linux)
2. make the server file system remotely accessible as a virtual hard drive
3. allocate SWAP file on this virtual hard drive for the client